# CW-structure on X/G

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

Let $X$ be a CW complex and G a group with a an action on X which freely permutes the cells of X. Is there a CW structure on the orbit complex X/G?

I will appreciate books references on Algebraic Topology in order to understand the corresponding definitions.

Comment: I’m a little confused by the question. If the cells are freely permuted, then in the quotient, isn’t there going to be one cell for each orbit? To me it just seems like all the cells in the same orbit get identified in the quotient. I’m assuming the cells being freely permuted are of the same dimension, of course.

Comment: @OsamaGhani I'm just trying to understand the Proposition 2.4 from Keneth Brown's Cohomoly of Groups. I have no to much experience with a course in Algebraic Topology. Maybe I must to reformulate my question:Let X be a CW complex and G a group with a an action on X which freely permutes the cells of X. Is there a CW structure on the orbit complex X/G?

Comment: Looking at the proof of that proposition, Brown states "But $C_\ast(Y)$ also has a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis with one element for each G-orbit of cells of $X$" which follows if we assume that $X/G$ has the CW structure given by one cell for each orbit, so I'm inclined to say yes.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Can you give some books references in order to have  a good exposition on G-complexes subject?

Comment: You could look at Allen Hatcher’s Algebraic Topology. It’s freely available. To look at groups acting on CW complexes, you can look toward the end of chapter 1 where he considers group actions that are covering space actions

Comment: Just to add to this. Hatcher doesn’t consider G-complexes explicitly but a couple of the examples (say $S^n \to \mathbb{R}P^n$) are G-complexes.